# Angular-How to use statusChanges on multiple dynamically created FormGroups?

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

In `ngOnInit()` I have a `forEach` method that generates some `FormGroups` with some `FormControls`. Then, I created an array containing the `statusChanges` of each `FormGroup`.

```
ticketsFormArr: FormGroup[] = [];

this.tickets.forEach(ticket => {
      this.ticketsFormArr.push(new FormGroup({
        ticketType: new FormControl('', Validators.required),
        rods: new FormControl('', Validators.required),
        firstName: new FormControl('', Validators.required),
        lastName: new FormControl('', Validators.required),
        email: new FormControl('', Validators.required),
      }))
    })

    this.ticketsFormArr.forEach(ticket => {
      this.obsArr.push(ticket.statusChanges);
    })
```

I want to check all of them at the same time if their status is `valid` because I have a button that gets a disabled class as long as at least one form is `invalid`.

First, I tried using a `forEach` and subscribing to each ticket with `ticket.statusChanges.subscribe()` but I realized it doesn't do both, only the form that is being edited.

```
this.ticketsFormArr.forEach(ticket => {
  console.log(ticket.status)

  ticket.statusChanges.subscribe(val => {
    console.log(val)
    console.log("stat", ticket.status)
```

Then I tried combining the `Observables` from `statusChanges` with `combineLatest`, `merge`, `concat`, `forkJoin`. I've managed to get their `statusChanges` but none of them seems to work as I would like to, either I get the same result as above, or I get only the initial logs with `EventEmitter`

I really have no idea how I could achieve this...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not necessary to do it with such an overloaded approach. You can achieve this pretty straight foreward as the `[disabled]` directive of your button fires repeatedly. It will notice a change within millis. Do it this way:

***TS***

```
/* returns true when at least one formGroup is invalid */
notAllFormGroupsAreValid(): boolean {
    return this.ticketsFormArr.findIndex(group => !group.valid) > -1;
}
```

***HTML***

```
<button [disabled]="notAllFormGroupsAreValid()"></button>
```

Comment: I was overcomplicating things so much, thank you!